# How do I revert one file to its original state in git?

Tags: git

I have a few files I made changes to.

Then I committed it and realized I made a change to a file I didn't want to change. How can I get the file back to its original state? I am on a branch.

```
git checkout --file
```

didn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
git checkout filename
```

will work in most cases, unless you have a branch with the same name as a file. In either case,

```
git checkout -- filename
```

will be sufficient.

Comment: Ad if you have added the file to staging already, you will have to unstage it first (`git reset filename`).

Comment: @Mike Or `git checkout @ -- filename` to specify that you'd like to check out from HEAD rather than from the index.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
git checkout HEAD~ filename
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need a space between `--` and your filename:

```
git checkout -- filename
```

Answer (score 3):

It isnt very clear to me what you mean by the original state. In my case however, the original state that I wanted to go back to was that of the master branch (off which I had branched off into a dev branch).

So to 'revert' a file.txt to the *master* branch version while checked out on a different dev branch, run:

```
git checkout master <full-path-to-file>\file.txt
```